# Issue with SocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I am currently going through CS50's web development course (just finished the JavaScript lecture) and have stumbled across an issue with web sockets using SocketIO. I ran the source code provided at this link: [Source code](http://cdn.cs50.net/web/2018/spring/lectures/5/src5.zip). I ran the program: "vote1".

When I run the program (after setting environment variable and running `flask run`), it takes a while to load and in the terminal, this is printed:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:57:23] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178643212-45 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178643232-46&sid=d8c5c5cf1dcc4cd8b06d4c629c980539 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178668231-47&sid=d8c5c5cf1dcc4cd8b06d4c629c980539 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "GET /static/index.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 16:58:24] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178704847-0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

After clicking on the 'Yes' button, the 'Yes votes' are meant to increase but they don't, instead after about 30 seconds, this prints in the terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 17:02:01] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178861393-1&sid=852b4c8df564432292c44c878643cf5d HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 17:02:01] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178869697-2&sid=852b4c8df564432292c44c878643cf5d HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 17:02:01] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178921417-3&sid=852b4c8df564432292c44c878643cf5d HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 17:02:01] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178921418-4&sid=852b4c8df564432292c44c878643cf5d HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2019 17:02:02] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1560178922496-5 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am using Firefox on Linux Mint (in case that could be an issue).

Any ideas on how to resolve this error so that the program works properly?

Edit:
I have found out that you should include:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    socketio.run(app)
```

I added this, but the same issue persists.

The post has been getting some down-votes and I assume this is because I posted a link to the source code. For those who would like to see the application.py file and the JavaScript file, I've added the code below:

Application.py:

```
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

votes = {"yes": 0, "no": 0, "maybe": 0}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", votes=votes)


@socketio.on("submit vote")
def vote(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    votes[selection] += 1
    emit("vote totals", votes, broadcast=True)
```

Index.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // Each button should emit a "submit vote" event
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = () => {
                const selection = button.dataset.vote;
                socket.emit('submit vote', {'selection': selection});
            };
        });
    });

    // When a new vote is announced, add to the unordered list
    socket.on('vote totals', data => {
        document.querySelector('#yes').innerHTML = data.yes;
        document.querySelector('#no').innerHTML = data.no;
        document.querySelector('#maybe').innerHTML = data.maybe;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. In the documentation of Flask-SocketIO, it states that you should use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Instead of running the app using `flask run`, just run it like it is a normal Python program.